# Does SQLite support "delete from from"

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-delete

This is valid syntax on Microsoft SQL Server's T-SQL, but not in SQLite, is there an alternative syntax that does the same in SQLite?

```
DELETE FROM something
FROM something
INNER JOIN combinations ON something.field1=combinations.field1
AND something.field2=combinations.field2
--optionally more criteria and/or more joins
WHERE combinations.field3=1234
--or anything really, just to show some criteria could be applied here also
```

Comment: @DerGolem: see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189835.aspx , a first `FROM` for the table/object/variable, a second `FROM` for a table source (optionally with joins)

Comment: Wow! never encountered such a syntax in my life... ;) And I worked with Access, Oracle, SQL Server, MySql and SQLite. You never finish learning...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the general case, move the entire join into a subquery that looks up the primary keys of the rows to be deleted:

```
DELETE FROM something
WHERE id IN (SELECT something.id
             FROM something
             JOIN combinations ON something.field1=combinations.field1
                              AND something.field2=combinations.field2
             WHERE combinations.something=1234)
```

If you have a composite primary key, you can use the [rowid](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid) instead:

```
DELETE FROM something
WHERE rowid IN (SELECT something.rowid
                FROM something
                JOIN combinations ON something.field1=combinations.field1
                                 AND something.field2=combinations.field2
                WHERE combinations.something=1234)
```

If you have a composite primary key and you created the table as a [WITHOUT ROWID](http://www.sqlite.org/withoutrowid.html) table, you have to rewrite the join as a correlated subquery:

```
DELETE FROM something
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM combinations
              WHERE field1 = something.field1
                AND field2 = something.field2
                AND field3 = 1234)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you have an alternative:

```
DELETE FROM slave
where slave.master_id in (select master.id from master where master.something=1234)
```

Comment: Ah, see, I may have oversimplified my example a bit. In places where I use this the ON sections of the JOIN(s) can get more complicated than a single value.

Comment: @StijnSanders Can you give an example please?